# In Jupyter Notebook, what indicates when the kernel has become ready after a restart?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter Notebook (version of the notebook server is 6.1.1), "Restart the Kernel" leads to waiting an unknown length of time before a "Kernel is Ready" message eventually flashes for just an instant in the bar at the top. If I miss seeing the flash, I end up waiting needlessly.

Is there an indicator somewhere showing when the kernel has become ready after a restart?

Answer (score 0):

In the upper-right corner under the logout button there is a kernel name with a colored status indicator to its right.  This is red when the kernel is not running and white (or clear) when the kernel is running.

Comment: That indicator stays white the whole time -- from before a restart until after the eventual "Kernel is Ready" message flashes briefly -- so it's of no help.

Comment: Not sure what to suggest -- I verified the behavior on Jupyter Notebook 6.1.1 running the Python 3 kernel with Chrome.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'm using Chrome and the SageMath 9.2 kernel.